# Java using jsoup to get text in html li tab

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div id="divEvents">

    <ul class="News_Title_Link">

    <li style="line-height:20px"><a href="/article/us-asia-storm-japan-idUSKBN1AO09Y" title="Now a tropical storm, Noru rakes Japan's main island">Now a tropical storm, Noru rakes Japan's main island</a> (21/03/2017 12:11)</li>

    <li style="line-height:20px"><a href="/article/us-southkorea-military-idUSKBN1AO0C9" title="South Korea's Moon taps Air Force chief to head Joint Chiefs of Staff">South Korea's Moon taps Air Force chief to head Joint Chiefs of Staff</a> (18/03/2015 17:16)</li>
```

I use jsoup to get the date and time, ex :"21/03/2017 12:11" but the output is "South Korea's Moon taps Air Force chief to head Joint Chiefs of Staff  (17/03/2017 17:16)".

Here is my code

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 Element time = doc.select("li").get(1);
 String text = time.text();
```

Can anyone help to fix the code to get only date and time.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe you wanted [`time.ownText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--) so as not to get the text of the sub-elements?

Comment: Thanks. time.ownText() works.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [time.ownText()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--) in order to get the text of the selected `<li>` element while excluding the text of the `<a>` sub-element of `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

Element time = doc.select("li").get(1);
Instead of using 1, place 0.

Element time = doc.select("li").get(0); //this will select the first li tag

Comment: I want to get time only not the whole text so i find out the correct code is time.ownText(). Anyway, thank you for your answer.